# How to show an event only once at a change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function in JS to check the date and compare the date with the input of the user.

The function run when the user change a input field. But I get the problem that the Error message stay twice or multiple times when the date is not correct when changing a input field. This because the function calculate runs on each change.

How can I say that if the error message showing on a change, disable the first one and remove the error message when the date is correct.

```
    function calculate(){
  if (thereIsMissingValue())
        return

  let formDate = getFormDate()
    let comparisonDate = getComparisonDate()
    let formNewDate = getNewDate()

    let isOlderThanComparison = formDate < comparisonDate
    let isNewerThanToday = formDate > formNewDate

    if(isOlderThanComparison) {
      $('#next-button').prop('disabled', true);
      var $newdiv1 = $( "<div id='error-form' class='error-form'><p>Error text</p></div>" );
      $(".gform_page_fields").prepend($newdiv1);
    }else if(isNewerThanToday) {
      $('#next-button').prop('disabled', true);
      var $newdiv2 = $( "<div id='error-form' class='error-form'><p>Error text 2</p></div>" );
      $(".gform_page_fields").prepend($newdiv2);
    }else {
      $('#next-button').prop('disabled', false);
      $( "#error-form" ).remove();
    }
}


$('#day, #month, #year, #hour, #minute').change(function(){
    calculate();
});
```

Tried

```
$('#day, #month, #year, #hour, #minute').one("change",function(){
    calculate();
});
```

But then the function runs only once

Comment: You can try using blur event (occurs when the element loses focus) and see if that meets your expectation. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/blur

Comment: @AndrewLohr no, that doesn't work because it shows no on each lose

Comment: Add some html and put your code in snippet[<>] of jsfiddle, it will be easier for us to help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would make more sense to have the error text div in the page, but hidden, then you could just show/hide it when required.  That way it doesn't matter how frequently it changes state - there will only be 1 error and it will always be relevant (or hidden)...

```
var $error = $("#error-form");

if(isOlderThanComparison) {
    $('#next-button').prop('disabled', true);
    $error.html("<p>Error text</p>");
    $error.show();
}
else if(isNewerThanToday) {
    $('#next-button').prop('disabled', true);
    $error.html("<p>Error text 2</p>");
    $error.show();
}else {
    $('#next-button').prop('disabled', false);
    $error.hide();
}
```

Just make sure to include the div in your page like this...

```
<div id="error-form"></div>
```

and add this to your css...

```
#error-form {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Can you give me more information?  In what way is it not working?  Is the change event still firing correctly?

Comment: I add the div with the correct ID #error-form. It doesn't add the error message to the DIV. The disable still works, but the error not.

Comment: Here is the code for the error: `<div id="#error-form"></div>`

Comment: Okay.  Selectors with a # at the front are looking for an element with the given id, so `$("#error-form")` will find an element with the id of `error-form` (no hash).  Change it to `<div id="error-form"></div>` and it will work :)

Comment: No worries - glad to help :)